# How to use game states in a simple FPS in JAVA

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine

So for my computer programming minor project, we have to create a game in JAVA. They have given us a very simple engine-esque application which simply displays a 3D maze from a first person view through which the user can navigate. It's our job to make it a "full" fledged FPS with enemies. We use JAVA and OpenGL (JOGL)

They have told us to use game states, but there was never a lecture about this and their answer was to google it. Well, what I googled is a tad bit too complicated to really grasp my head around, so I'll just ask specific questions with regards to the states.

The game needs to have states for thing like pausing and the main menu. However, I also read that the player itself can also have states such as different firing modes.

1. How would a UML diagram, or any diagram look like which includes a state class? Is it a hierarchical structure where the state class is on top?
2. Are all states defined in a single state class? It's a simple game so we have: shooting, pausing, main menu, sprinting, ducking, health packs. (Maybe difficulties).
3. If for example ESC is pressed, a method in UserInput will be fired. I assume that I somehow have to change the state of the game. This is kind of a sub question of question 1. What would be a clean way to change the state of the game? As in, how would I contact the state class?

Are all of those states?

Here is a UML diagram of what we have. 
[image: UML Diagram of the game]

Comment: a state transition diagram would give a better visualization of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlecTeal Read my first sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the past I have used manually coded ints (effectively an enum).

For example:

```
// "GAME" application state sub states;
private int GAMESTATE;
private static final int INTRO = 0;
private static final int PLAYING = 1;
private static final int OUTRO = 2;
```

then based on the value of GAMESTATE I could control the branching of the game code.

My preferred way of creating states though is to make a state manager class which allow instanciation of a new state at need, and can control what states are active, as well as what valid state to state movement is allowed (for example allow `intro` state to `play` state but not `intro` state to victory `state`)

(an example of something similar is located [here](http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/game-state-management/) for C++ but it is trivial to implement the same functionality in java based on that code:)

I have just found an old set of my code which has the following (forgive the formatting it is from about 10 years ago, and designed for minimal line count layout):

**GameStateManager.java**

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.*;

public class GameStateManager {

    public static final String EXIT_GAME = "_ExitGame";

    private Map gameStates;
    private Image defaultImage;
    private GameState currentState;
    private InputManager inputManager;
    private boolean done;

    public GameStateManager(InputManager inputManager,
        Image defaultImage)
    {
        this.inputManager = inputManager;
        this.defaultImage = defaultImage;
        gameStates = new HashMap();
    }

    public void addState(GameState state) {        gameStates.put(state.getName(), state);    }

    public Iterator getStates() {        return gameStates.values().iterator();    }

    public void loadAllResources(ResourceManager resourceManager) {
        Iterator i = getStates();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            GameState gameState = (GameState)i.next();
            gameState.loadResources(resourceManager);
        }
    }

    public boolean isDone() {        return done;    }

    public void setState(String name) {
        // clean up old state
        if (currentState != null) {            currentState.stop();        }
        inputManager.clearAllMaps();

        if (name == EXIT_GAME) {            done = true;        }
        else {
            // set new state
            currentState = (GameState)gameStates.get(name);
            if (currentState != null) {                currentState.start(inputManager);            }
        }
    }

    public void update(long elapsedTime) {
        // if no state, pause a short time
        if (currentState == null) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        }
        else {
            String nextState = currentState.checkForStateChange();
            if (nextState != null) {                setState(nextState);            }
            else {                currentState.update(elapsedTime);            }
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        if (currentState != null) {            currentState.draw(g);        }
        // if no state, draw the default image to the screen
        else {     g.drawImage(defaultImage, 0, 0, null);        }
    }
}
```

**GameState.java**  (Interface)

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public interface GameState {

public String getName();
//    Returns the name of a state to change to if this state is
//    ready to change to another state, or null otherwise.
public String checkForStateChange();
//    Loads any resources for this state. This method is called
//    in a background thread before any GameStates are set.
public void loadResources(ResourceManager resourceManager);
//    Initializes this state and sets up the input manager
public void start(InputManager inputManager);
//    Performs any actions needed to stop this state.
public void stop();
//    Updates world, handles input.
public void update(long elapsedTime);
//    Draws to the screen.
public void draw(Graphics2D g);
}
```

You will also need an implementation of an `InputManager` and a `ResourceManager`, but hopefully this helps you a bit:)

Let me know if you need more info as there are a couple of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to mention is that I'm not a game developer but I've got some years of experience in java. To do those states such as pausing a game, or different firing modes, I would use enumerations.

Take a look at these: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/waseem-quraishi/java-enumerations